# How to add a blank "column" at specific index in excel through python?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy, csv

I've tried by using this script.But,It just overlap in single "column" only. In "H", column name was "Unit of Arrivals" but when I add a column name "APMC" at "0" index it just overlap into the "Unit of Arrivals". I want to add a new column at "0" index named "APMC"

```
import pandas as pd                                                          
import numpy as np                                                              
import csv    

df = pd.read_csv('/home/hirensoni/Documents/arpit/mt.csv',error_bad_lines=False,index_col=0)
df.insert(0,"APMC",np.NaN)
df.to_csv("/home/hirensoni/Documents/arpit/mt.csv") 
print(df.head(5))
```

The Result in excel file after running my script:-

[Open This Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TkI33.png)

What I want is :-

[Open This Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/itCGG.png)

Comment: is it doesn't work..display the dataframe..

Comment: why you give index_col = 0..can you explain please.

Comment: Because it was showing "Unamed 2.0" and create a new column by this name so to overcome that error, "index_col=0" works. @yid

Comment: here you are creating a new column only not inserting the data

Comment: Yes, I just want to create a blank column only naming "APMC" with no data @yid. Here, "APMC","Commodity","Arrivals" & "Unit of Arrivals". are the "Column Names"

Comment: I've linked the Screenshots of my output in my question, hope it helps  you to solve my problem @yid

Comment: I have updated my answer check it.

Comment: No, the output is same as what I've got so far. @yid

Answer (score 0):

Initially

I think you are expecting these kind of output only[image: Orginal data]

Instend of this

```
df.insert(0,"APMC",np.NaN)
```

Replace this

```
df.insert(0,"APMC",'')
```

After Replacing

[image: After adding column]

you are expecting this kind of output correct

Comment: Yes, I just want same like this but even after making changes to my code the output is same as it is. @yid